# QGIS Vertex Tool not working on some layers

Tags: vertices, qgis-custom-function

I am making a map in QGIS 3.16.
I have made a custom function with the function editor.
I have used the function in the styles of 5 layers of my map.
When I start QGIS all layers load correctly with correct calculations of my function.
But Vertex Tool is working normally on the the 5th layer and on all the layers not using my function.
If I remove my function from the style of any of the 4 layers, the Vertex Tool starts working correctly.
I have also made a test layer.  This layer works as the 4 layers.
I have tried hard to find the reason, why the 5th layer is an exception. But I can't find any essential difference between the style of this layer and the other 4 styles.

See my example in "QGIS : On layers using my custom function and also having a Rule (Filter) the Vertex Tool is not working"

Comment: what are you using your function to do?

Comment: I am using the function to regulate the size of objects according to the map scale